# HTML/JS: Change inner.HTML and reset it back

Tags: javascript, html

So I have got this HTML-Code

```
<button id="demo" onclick="toogleFunction()">Login</button>
```

and this JS-Code

```
function toogleFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById('but_login');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Insert your data!";
}
```

The code does what it sould do:
- it is showing me the spoiler
- the name changes

My question is: How can I do it so that it changes the name back to "login", when I click again on the button, or when I click on another button.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to say login when the but_login is visible ?

Comment: My fault. The but_login is for the container which I get to see when I click on the button:
<div id="but_login" style="display:none">
          <label> Email address </label>

Comment: I have the button with the label/name "Login".
When I click it it shows me the content of the <div> and the name of the button changes to "Insert your data!"
Now I want that when I click on it again, it gets the name Login again.

Answer (score 2):

```
function toogleFunction()
 {
    var x = document.getElementById('but_login');
    var demo  = document.getElementById("demo")
    var text  = demo.innerText;

    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if(text === "Login"){
      demo.innerText = "Insert your data!";
    }else{
      demo.innerText = "Login";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working.
The container does not open anymore and the names do not change.

Comment: one sec ill change it

Comment: Hell yeah. Thank you Sir. :D

Comment: Sweet, No Problem :)